# mat-slide-toggle' is not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-material, slider

when I am trying to add slider in angular getting below error

error NG8001: 'mat-slide-toggle' is not a known element:

1. If 'mat-slide-toggle' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-slide-toggle' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

I have tried adding `import {MatSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';` under app.module.ts file and also added `MatSlideToggleModule` under @NgModule under imports section but still I am getting the error.

I am using angular CLI 13.1.2 however project is built using 12.2.3

Providing screenshot FYR.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2inf.png)

Comment: You need to provide more information like code of module and error screenshot otherwise we can't guess what is issue

Comment: @DevangPatel added image FYR

Comment: Your module to import appears to be correct, can you put your module and ts code here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA in schemas under app.modules.ts file resolved the issue